# Integration of Spring Batch with a web application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm working on a web application that accepts a csv file, parses its contents and stores them in a db.
I'm using spring boot.

I read [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) tutorial about spring batch.

**Question #1**
The purpose of Spring Batch is to implement only stand alone programs or could it be efficiently integrated into a web application?
I'm wondering if, for my use case, a combination of `FileInputStream` and `InputStreamReader` to parse the file maybe more simple and straight forward, while using Spring Batch could be a little overkill.

**Question #2**
I didn't find any example, or tutorial, or documentation page that explains how to call (run) a *"batch job"* from a web application (for example from a method of the controller). In the aforementioned tutorial the job is "hooked" from the application, there's nothing like a `job.run()`, it just executes when the batch demo application is run. How could it be made? Is there any place where something like my specific use case is explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question #1**

Using Spring Batch from a web application may be a good idea because you get all the benefits from Spring Batch.

**Question #2**

Inject the `JobLauncher` instance. JobLauncher is the class used to run batch jobs.

Please read the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer